# How to return empty if object has no attribute 'casefold'

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have currently two different dict where in one data its empty and with data, and I want to compare the data between them and see if the stock is higher than the previous data. Here is a proof of concept I have done:

```py
STOCK_MAP = {
    'oos': 0,
    'low': 1,
    'medium': 2,
    'high': 3
}

data_1 = {}

data2 = {
    '123456789':
        {
            'levels': '123456789',
            'stock': 'LOW',
        }
}

t = any(STOCK_MAP[value['stock'].casefold()] > STOCK_MAP[data_1.get(att, {}).get('stock', {}).casefold()] for att, value in data2.items())
print(t)
```

My guess is that I need to somehow make a way where `STOCK_MAP[value['stock'].casefold()]` or/and `STOCK_MAP[data_1.get(att, {}).get('stock', {}).casefold()]` returns as 0 if the variable is not found and my guess is that it throws the error `['dict' object has no attribute 'casefold']` due to it cannot translate the dict with casefold?

My question is, how can I make a way with this code that if it doesn't find the variable 'stock' in the data then it should "mark" it as 0?

Expected:

It should not throw the error `['dict' object has no attribute 'casefold']` whenever there is not a variable found

Actual:

Throws: ['dict' object has no attribute 'casefold']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use

`value["stock"].casefold() if hasattr(value["stock"], "casefold") else 0`

Comment: Where in the code should I put it?

Comment: The place(s) where you want this value.

Comment: Inside the any(...) ?

Comment: It's not entirely clear whether you would want e.g. `STOCK_MAP[value['stock'].casefold() if hasattr(value['stock'], 'casefold' else 0]` or perhaps `STOCK_MAP[value['stock'].casefold() if hasattr(value['stock'], 'casefold'] else 0`

Comment: what is the difference between those two code you sent?

Comment: One produces `STOCK_MAP[0]` and the other produces `0` (I hope ... not in a place where I can test)

Comment: I think I would rather have the first option so meaning inside the STOCK_MAP :) Thanks! however it seems like the code will be very long. `any(STOCK_MAP[value["stock"].casefold() if hasattr(value["stock"], "casefold") else 'oos'] > STOCK_MAP[data_1[att]["stock"].casefold() if hasattr(data_1.get(att, {}).get('stock', {}), "casefold") else 'oos'] for att, value in data2.items())` - Any way to shorter it perhaps?

Comment: You could copy the array to a different one, then operate on that. If the array is really big, that might create new problems, though. `temp = [value["stock"].casefold if hasattr(value["stock"], "casefold" else 0]`